# Subprocess command throwing error while converting docx to pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx, doc

I'm running the following code on my windows machine using python's subprocess module.

```
import subprocess

args = ["abiword --to=pdf '{}'".format('test.docx')]
process = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, timeout=None)
print(process.stdout.decode())
filename = re.search('-> (.*?) using filter', process.stdout.decode())
print(filename.group(1))
```

But `subprocess.run` gives the following error:

```
b'\'"abiword --to=pdf \'test.docx\'"\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n'
```

How to resolve this error and how should I proceed now?
Also, is it correct to use `abiword` command in my windows machine? I want to convert my docx to pdf without installing any third party software like libreoffice.

Comment: Is `abiword` installed on your machine and is it available in the PATH? Said differently, what happens if you type `abiword --to-pdf test.docx` in a aconsole CMD.exe window?

Comment: yes I have installed abiword on my win machine and the Path variable has been updated with the .exe file path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AbiWord\bin'.
I don't see any error when I do `abiword --to-pdf test.docx` on cmd but I don't see any pdf getting created.

Comment: @k-j It's 2.9.4

Comment: I installed 2.8.4 but that also didn't work. The command line doesn't generate any pdf. I used Libreoffice but that doesn't maintain the alignment of tables and images. Don't know what other module should I use.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 different problems here.

First one will be simple to solve: you do not give the correct parameters to subprocess. The first parameter (args) can be either a string which contains the full command line or a list containing the command and parameters as separate elements. So you should use either:

```
args = "abiword --to=pdf '{}'".format('test.docx')
```

(a simple string and not a list) or:

```
args = ["abiword", "--to=pdf",  '{}'.format('test.docx')]
```

The second one is that until you can generate the pdf by entering the `abiword --to-pdf` command in a console CMD.exe window, the same command launched with `subprocess.run` will not give better results...

Comment: `'{}'.format('test.docx')` is just a wicked complicated way to write `'test.docx'`

Comment: @tripleee: You are right, but I did not want to change that part because it is fully unrelated to OP problem.

Comment: On Windows, the difference between `shell=True` or not is smaller, but for the record, the only _portable_ way to use the second form is to also remove the `shell=True`. Perhaps see also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: Probably also add `check=True` to have Python raise an exception if `abiword` fails for some reason.

Comment: @serge-ballesta The command is not throwing any error but it's not generating the PDF as well.
I tried another method to convert docx to pdf using Libreoffice and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Use the full path to abiword: `/usr/bin/abiword`

Comment: That would help if the command they were trying to execute was actually `abiword`, but as per the error message, it's not.